# Setting and unsetting cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a button that can be toggled on and off by adding and removing classes, when clicked to off, I need it to stay in that state and vice versa, the cookie I assigned to the 'off' state works but when I want to toggle it back to on I can't remove the cookie.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".button2").click(function () {
    if($(".toggle2").hasClass("toggleOn")) {
      $(".toggle2").removeClass("toggleOn");
      $(".toggle2").addClass("toggleOff");
      $.cookie('setting1', 'off', { expires: 1, path: '/', domain: '#' });
    } else {
      $(".toggle2").removeClass("toggleOff");
      $(".toggle2").addClass("toggleOn");
      $.cookie('setting1', null, { expires: 1, path: '/', domain:     '#' });
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  if($.cookie('setting1') == null) {

  } else {
    $(".toggle2").removeClass("toggleOn");
    $(".toggle2").addClass("toggleOff");
    $(".buttonON2").removeClass("buttOnAnimate");
    $(".buttonON2").addClass("buttOnAnimateRemove");
    $(".buttonOFF2").removeClass("buttOffAnimateremove");
    $(".buttonOFF2").addClass("buttOffAnimateADD");
  };
});
```

I'm fairly new to the concept of cookies, I read up that assigning null to the value would follow the if statement of the cookies which is nothing thereby ignoring the else statement. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If your goal is to remove the cookie you can use `$.removeCookie("cookie_name");`

Comment: use `localStorage` for new HTML5 supported browsers. Ex.http://stackoverflow.com/a/39832070/6608101

Comment: @Franco Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use removeCookie to remove a cookie

```
$.removeCookie('setting1');
```

for newer version of jquery.cookie use

```
Cookies.remove('setting1');
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work, I don't know If I've got an outdated jquery.cookie.js file. I did find an alternative - $.cookie('setting1', '', { expires: -1, path: '#' }); - Not sure if It's recommended though